# Is there any non-recursive/stack-consuming, bottom-up binary tree traversal algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, language-agnostic

Suppose you want to write a simple math reducer that will, for example, do the transformation:

```
((add ((add 2) 3)) ((add 4) 2)) -> 11
```

A simple algorithm could be (example in JavaScript):

```
function r(a){
    if (typeof(a)!=="object") return a;
    var a = [r(a[0]), r(a[1])];
    return a[0][0]==="add" ? a[0][1] + a[1] : a;
}
console.assert(r([["add",[["add",2],3]],[["add",4],2]]) === 11);
```

Is it possible to solve the same problem with constant stack?

Comment: non-recursive ... recursive?

Comment: Bad wording, I'm still not sure how to title this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking either. If it can't be recursive and it can't produce a stack then what exactly is allowed? You want to traverse a tree but it can't build a call stack?

Comment: I want to solve that problem without building a stack - which I guess is the same as saying that I want to transverse a binary tree without doing so (is it impossible?)

Comment: Yes, you can make *any* recursive program iterative by using a stack (data structure) on the heap.

Comment: I guess OP asking if it possible to traverse tree bottom-up using only O(1) space. I guess, it's possible if you have direct pointers to tree leaves and nodes have pointers to their parents. What I'm not sure is if it possible to _build_ such tree using algo w/ O(1) space.

Comment: @VictorSorokin I could use a specialized data-structure for that without problems - that is, no worries about the building phase - but your comment alone isn't enough for me to figure out what you mean.

Comment: @Viclib you just point a working pointer at the root, make a loop `while(not done){ ... }` and move a working pointer around, detecting the reducing condition, replacing nodes with values when you can, until `done`.

Answer (score 1):

Any recursive algorithm can be emulated using a stack on the heap and a loop. So, yes, it is possible to do this in a single function call.

If you are talking about traversing a *single*-linked tree in *constant space* (both stack and heap), then no, you cannot do that (you have to remember your way back up).

Comment: I'm upvoting you, but I think the last statement is false - see Morris Inorder Tree Transversal. I'm just not sure how to adapt this algorithm to my problem.

Comment: @Viclib: "Morris Inorder Tree Transversal" adds _additional_ linking structure which is explicitly excluded by the wording "_single_-linked tree".

Answer (score 1):

If you transform your tree structure to [zipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_%28data_structure%29) so you can traverse it using state machine. It is no longer simple tree but allows you make it non-recursive or tail recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to do a depth-first traversal of a binary tree without using recursion, explicitly maintaining a stack, or modifying the tree nodes.

The resulting algorithm requires O(1) extra space and O(n^2) time.